# Is it possible to hide UINavigationController then show it when user swipe down?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, show-hide

I have a view that I want to have full screen, I'm hiding system bar and `UINavigationBar` but I would like to have it re-appear on some user interaction e.g. drag content down or press near top edge etc. (which ever is easier to implement and more user friendly).

I've searched with no success so far thus my question on SO.

EDIT:
Worth to mention is that this view that is displayed full screen is UIWebView and UINavigationBar is used on this view to give "go back" ability with back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive it's possible.

If you want some simple user interactions like drag down, then you need to use `UIScrollView` and implement its delegate. After that, you can use some of these methods

`– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`

`– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`

Then just show/hide the `UINavigationBar` afterward

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES/NO animated:YES];`

---

If the logic above does not work. You can fake the `UINavigationBar` with an `UIView`. It's easy to show and hide it with these delegate.

//Edit: if you don't want to use `UIScrollView`, you can use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and check if the gesture is a drag down/up or not. However, I think using `UIScrollView` will be much easier.

---

//Update:
You can still use `UIScrollView` and `UIWebView`. Like this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //init an UIScrollView and UIWebView
    [self.view addSubview:theScrollView];
    [theScrollView addSubview:theWebView]; 

    //back button
    UIButton *back = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    //custom button: set its frame, title, image ...

    //set action for button
    [back addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction:) forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //add to view
    [theWebView addSubView: back]; //or [self.view addSubView:back]; --both will work just fine

}

-(void)backAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //if you use navigation push, use this
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //if you use navigation modal, add this line of code to its previous view controller
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

Done ! :)

Comment: It seems like it ma work:) however with my 2mnth experience with mac and objective-c it is still like abra-cadabra:) I will update my question to mention that this view is using UIWebView for which I would like to have all space but give ability to go back with the UINavigationBar.

Comment: you can still do it ask I suggested. I will update my answer in few minutes.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow:) but nit exactly as you proposed because UIWebView already has UIScrollView - so I just use those scroll handlers.

Comment: I have used the `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate` and when user dragged far enough `if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < -32){}` then I animate IN the `UINavigationBar`.